# How to produce fancybox with tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I would like to create a fancy box like the one below.
[image]
But so far I managed to produce the image below which is actually not what I need.
[image]
MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{myex}[1][]{ 
before=\bigskip\centering,
after=\bigskip,
breakable, 
enhanced, 
arc=15pt, 
colback=white, 
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
title=Ex~\thetcbcounter,
frame hidden, 
sharp corners, 
rounded corners=southeast, 
attach boxed title to top left, 
boxed title style={ 
 enhanced, 
 colframe=purple!65!blue, 
 colback=purple!65!blue, 
 arc=5pt, 
 borderline east={2pt}{6pt}{white}, 
 borderline east={2pt}{2pt}{white}, 
 bottomrule=0pt, 
 rightrule=0pt, 
 sharp corners, 
}, 
interior style={}, 
 overlay={ 
 \draw[line width=1pt,purple!65!blue]([xshift=-3pt,yshift=.6cm]frame.north 
west)--([xshift=-3pt]frame.south west); 
 \draw[rounded corners=20pt,line width=1pt,purple!65!blue] ([xshift=-
3pt]frame.south west) -- (frame.south east)--(frame.north east); 
 \draw ([yshift=.6cm]frame.south east)--(frame.north east)--
([xshift=10cm]frame.north west); 
 } 
}
\begin{document} 
\begin{myex} 
What is meant by \textbf{electron affinity}. 
\end{myex} 
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
Something like this?

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\xdefinecolor{pBlue}{RGB}{102, 53, 153}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{myex}[1][]{%
  before=\bigskip\centering,
  after=\bigskip,
  breakable, 
  enhanced, 
  colback=white, 
  frame hidden, 
  sharp corners, 
  rounded corners=southeast,
  arc=25pt, 
  fonttitle=\sffamily, % \bfseries,
  title=Ex~\thetcbcounter,
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5pt}, %, xshifttext=5pt}, 
  boxed title style={%
    enhanced, 
    colframe=pBlue, 
    colback=pBlue, 
    borderline east={1.5pt}{8pt}{white}, 
    borderline east={1.5pt}{3.5pt}{white},
    borderline east={3.5pt}{0pt}{white},    
    borderline east={2.75pt}{0.25pt}{pBlue!50},    
    borderline east={2.75pt}{-4pt}{pBlue!20},    
    bottomrule=0pt, 
    rightrule=5pt, 
    sharp corners, 
  }, 
  interior style={}, 
  overlay={%
    \begin{scope}[line width=1.5pt, pBlue]
      \fill[shade, bottom color=pBlue!30, top color=white]
      ([xshift=-30pt]frame.south east)
      to[out=0, in=-90] ([yshift=30pt]frame.south east)
      -- ([shift={(-1pt, 15pt)}]frame.south east)
      to[out=-90, in=0] ([xshift=-25pt]frame.south east);
      \draw
      ([shift={(-1pt, 19pt)}]frame.north west) coordinate (iniPoint)
      -- ([xshift=-1pt]frame.south west)
      -- ([xshift=-30pt]frame.south east)
      to[out=0, in=-90] ([yshift=30pt]frame.south east)
      -- (frame.north east) -- ++(-2.5, 0) coordinate (endPoint);
      \draw (endPoint) -- ++(-3pt, 3pt) -- ++(-3pt, -3pt)
      -- ++(3pt, -3pt) -- cycle;
      \draw (iniPoint) -- ++(4pt, 0) -- ++(-8pt, 0);
      \draw (iniPoint) ++(0, -10pt) -- ++(6pt, 0) -- ++(-12pt, 0);
      \draw (iniPoint) ++(0, -14pt) -- ++(6pt, 0) -- ++(-12pt, 0);
    \end{scope}
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{myex} 
  What is meant by \textbf{electron affinity}:
  \lipsum[1]
\end{myex} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much respect @Daniel N

Comment: Many thanks.  I'm glad you can use it.